# Pass in and store function pointer to object

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I'm writing a basic GUI framework as a school project and I'm trying to create an object (think a button) that, when interacted with, will call a particular function.

To explain my setup simply, I have a button class and a window manager class. The window manager is instantiated once from main and many buttons are instantiated from the window manager, with all 3 being in separate files. Nothing should go in main.

I'm a bit of a C++ noob, but as far as I can see, it would be best to use function pointers for this. My idea is to instantiate my button object then to pass it a function pointer to a function that when called would edit another object.

Firstly, I presume that the best way to do this would be to have the functions be defined locally to the window manager otherwise I'd have trouble with access? I had wanted to initially not have them listed in the header to make things easier (with a view to creating a kind of drag and drop editor in the future).

Second, how would I pass (from the window manager) a pointer to a function (which would exist within the window manager) to an instance of a button object? I thought I'd be able to treat it similarly to any other variable and do something as:

```
Button btn1 = new Button();
btn1->SetText("Button 1");
btn1->SetOnClick(functionpointer);
```

But, after looking through various tutorials I don't quite understand how I'd implement this. For example, how do I even define somewhere to store the function pointer in my button class?

Would appreciate any insight, I think I've confused myself enough for one day.

**EDIT: Seems I should add that my `Button` and `WindowManager` classes are in separate files and my entry point so to speak is an instance of `WindowManager`. All the setup of my GUI including assigning a function to a button would be done in the constructor of `WindowManager`.**

Comment: You can take a look at `std::function`. It is basically a class template which can store function objects or function pointers. In your can, WindowManager class can simply contain function definitions and Button class can have member variable of type `std::function` and then WindowManager class can pass `std::function` object in constructor of Button class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with pointer to member function like this (in this case Button has to know WindowManager);

```
class WindowManager
{
public:
    typedef void (WindowManager::* TypeOnClickFunc)( void );

    void anyfunction( void ) {}
};

class Button
{
public:

    Button( WindowManager * wm ) :_windowmanager( wm ) {}

    void SetOnClick( WindowManager::TypeOnClickFunc fptr )
    {
        _onclickfptr = fptr;
    }

    void OnClick( void )
    {
        (_windowmanager->*_onclickfptr )( ); // indirect call WindowManager::anyfunction
    }

private:

    WindowManager *_windowmanager;
    WindowManager::TypeOnClickFunc _onclickfptr;
};

WindowManager wm;

Button *btn1 = new Button( &wm );
btn1->SetOnClick( &WindowManager::anyfunction );
```

... or with pointer to static function like this ...

```
class WindowManager
{
public:
    typedef void (*TypeOnClickFunc)( void );

    static void anyfunction( void ) {}
};

class Button
{
public:

    Button() {}

    void SetOnClick( WindowManager::TypeOnClickFunc fptr )
    {
        _onclickfptr = fptr;
    }

    void OnClick( void )
    {
        (*_onclickfptr )( ); // indirect call static WindowManager::anyfunction
    }

private:

    WindowManager::TypeOnClickFunc _onclickfptr;
};

Button *btn1 = new Button();
btn1->SetOnClick( &WindowManager::anyfunction );
```

... with typdef in Button instead of WindowManager ...

```
class WindowManager
{
public:
    static void anyfunction( void ) {}
};

class Button
{
public:
    typedef void (*TypeOnClickFunc)( void );

    Button() {}

    void SetOnClick( TypeOnClickFunc fptr )
    {
        _onclickfptr = fptr;
    }

    void OnClick( void )
    {
        (*_onclickfptr )( ); // indirect call 
    }

private:
    TypeOnClickFunc _onclickfptr;
};

Button *btn1 = new Button();
btn1->SetOnClick( &WindowManager::anyfunction );
```

Comment: On ` WindowManager::TypeOnClickFunc _onclickfptr;` I'm getting the error `use of undefined type 'WindowManager'` despite having included windowmanager.h. Will this method work if I have the two classes in separate files as wel ass having `btn1->SetOnClick()` being called from a setup function within `WindowManager`?

Comment: Both are already included. VisualStudio seems to recognise everything as intellisense doesn't throw any issues but upon building the compiler complains about the undefined type.

Comment: I've absolutely no idea what happened the first time I tried it but I'd obviously broken something somewhere and I had a page of errors. Started over and it's working perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Here is one approach by using function pointers. However using `std::function` makes the code more flexible. For example you can use lambda expressions.
To use `std::function` you can simply change the typedef to `typedef std::function<void(Button*)> EventCallback;` and add  the include `#include <functional>`

```
#include <iostream>

class Button
{
public:
    // Typedef of the event function signature
    typedef void(*EventCallback)(Button* button);

    Button() : onClick(nullptr) {}

    // Set the function to call
    void SetOnClick(EventCallback func) { onClick = func; }
    // Call the function if exists
    void OnClick() {
        if (onClick)
            onClick(this);
    }

private:
    // This stores the function pointer for the button
    EventCallback onClick;
};

// just some example function that has the same signature as Button::EventCallback
void MyEventFunc(Button* button)
{
    std::cout << "Triggered" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Button button;
    button.SetOnClick(&MyEventFunc);
    button.OnClick();
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/x5O49B

Comment: Curious, the `typedef` has to occur in public for it to be accessible outside of the button class (in the case I'm using separate class and header files) right? In your example, `onClick` is defined  below the `onClick(nullptr)` line meaning it's not defined. Moving private above public only solves this if the `typedef` occurs above both public and private, or `onClick` is moved into public.

Comment: And what exactly is `Button() : onClick(nullptr) {}` doing in this case?

Comment: @Jamie4840 Yes, the typedef would need to be public if you use it elsewhere outside of the class. But it is just an alias for the type so you can use the typedef inside the class and the type itself elsewhere without the typedef.

The `Button()` is a default constructor that ensures that `onClick` is initialized to a null pointer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406931/pointer-member-variable-initialization-in-c-classes

Comment: @Jamie4840 note that onClick is a member variable (the function pointer to store) and OnClick is a member function. Careful with that case sensitivity. You can move the class member functions and variables around as you please, but the typedef needs to be above it's use cases. So in other words because onClick is defined in the class it is defined everywhere in the class - even above the actual definition.

Comment: I'm struggling to get this working myself. Everything that is occurring in `main()` in your example is occurring in a function within `WindowManager` for me, lets say `InitGUI`. Therefore, my `MyEventFunc` also has to be a function within `WindowManager`. In this case, trying to make a pointer `&MyEventFunc` from `InitGUI` gives me `'&': illegal operation on bound member function expression`. Is it possible for it to work this way?

Comment: @Jamie4840 I believe this was already answered by Gernot, but here is a small example for a static function that you seemed to be using: http://ideone.com/xzbR8d There are comments on what needs to be included for what part of code if the code is split into different files.