# Default value of pointer

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

I already knew that value of pointer member of class is `undefined` if it is not initialized in constructor (refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406931/pointer-member-variable-initialization-in-c-classes?rq=1)). I made a simple example to test it.

main.cc

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        count = 10;
    }

    void test() {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << count << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int count;
};

class Bar {
public:
    void bar() {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        std::cout << m_foo << std::endl;
        m_foo->test();
        m_foo = new Foo();
        std::cout << m_foo << std::endl;
    }

private:
    Foo *m_foo;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    Bar bar;
    bar.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

If I use `g++`:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cc -o test
```

It runs with error as expected:

```
main
bar
0
Segmentation fault
```

But, if I change to compile with `clang++`:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 main.cc -o test
```

It runs without any error:

```
main
bar
0x400920
test-1991643855
Foo
0x1bf6030
```

As you see, although the pointer is not initialized, it has address not NULL and it can call the function `test` normally. How can I prevent this error with `clang++`?

Comment: It's undefined behavior. Don't try to make sense of it. It's futile.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "default value" for pointers. `m_foo` is not initialized, period. So dereferencing it is undefined behaviour. Be aware that "undefined behaviour" includes "apparently working fine".

Declare `m_foo` like this:

```
Foo * m_foo = nullptr;
```

Dereferencing a `nullptr` is still undefined behaviour, but on most platforms this will trigger a segmentation fault.